# python: Mac can read all files in a directory but Windows can't?

Tags: python

This is probably a naive question since I am absolutely a newbie to python...

I was trying to read a bunch of .txt files from a directory using Mac, and it worked perfectly, obtaining all the files without any exceptions.

But then I realized I needed to switch to another Window computer to do the computing... and it just wouldn't read all the files.

Here is an illustration:

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
from __future__ import print_function

# read all .txt files in directory

names = []
for file in os.listdir("Data/text/film/topy/"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        print(file)
        names.append(file)

scripts = [[] for _ in range(len(names)) ]
for i in xrange(len(names)):
    scripts[i] = np.genfromtxt("Data/text/film/topy/"+names[i],  delimiter="\t",dtype=character,skip_header=1)
```

names is a list for the .txt file names and scripts is a list comprehension for file contents.

There should be 365 files in there, and with Mac I could read all of them, but with Windows, only 357 files could be read...

the file names are like these:

```
l_10-Things-I-Hate-About-You.txt
l_12.txt
l_17-Again.txt
l_30-Minutes-or-Less.txt
l_48-Hrs..txt
l_50-50.txt
l_500-Days-of-Summer.txt
l_A-Serious-Man.txt
l_Adaptation.txt
l_Addams-Family,-The.txt
l_Adventures-of-Buckaroo-Banzai-Across-the-Eighth-Dimension,-The.txt
l_After-School-Special.txt
```

......

Is there certain files name that prevents Windows from reading? Does anyone know the difference and why is it? Super appreciated!!

Comment: `[...] and am too lazy to single out the missed ones [...]` and we are too lazy to reverse engineer your problems! Please be more precise on the issue you have.

Comment: When you say "only 357 files could be read", do you mean that `names` only contains 357 filenames? I know Windows is case insensitive, don't know about Mac - maybe the problem is filenames that differ only in case?

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes my windows computer returns `names` as a list of 357 items rather than 365 items read with Mac. All my filenames are different... Thanks for your input!!

Comment: @MeredithHu have you considered what happens when the file name doesn't end with ".txt" but, say, ".TXT" or a variation of upper & lower case? What happens if you change the `if` statement to match on the lower case version of the file name? (You probably want to generate a dummy copy of the file name converted to all lower case for that and check against the dummy file name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows has restrictions on the characters that can be contained in a file name. From [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set (128–255), except for the following:
>
> The following reserved characters:
>
> - `<` (less than)
> - `>` (greater than)
> - `:` (colon)
> - `"` (double quote)
> - `/` (forward slash)
> - `\` (backslash)
> - `|` (vertical bar or pipe)
> - `?` (question mark)
> - `*` (asterisk)
> - Integer value zero, sometimes referred to as the ASCII NUL character.
> - Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1 through 31, except for alternate data streams where these characters are allowed. For more information about file streams, see File Streams.

If any of your file names contains one of these characters, it will be unreadable on a Windows system.

Comment: @Meredith: Please tell us how this solved your problem.